# ASP.NET - accept multilanguage input and display correctly

Tags: asp.net, unicode, internationalization, multilingual

I have a basic web form in asp.net for recording some basic information.

How do I ensure that I can accept information in any language, store in sql and then redisplay on another webpage correctly. At the moment accents on certain characheters are displaying incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your field data type in the SQL DB is Nvarchar, Nvarchar support unicode

Check for SQL Datatype Details..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst126.htm

Comment: Yes NVARCHAR supports multibyte characters